# jQuery fadeIn is blinking in Firefox

Tags: jquery, fadein

I am using `fadeIn` to expand row in the table after user clicks. Everything works correct in Chrome and even IE, but it doesn't work in Firefox 15.0.1. In FF after expanded row is faded in it's background blinks one time.

Here is my code:

```
$('.patients-items-item').click(function() {
    var item = $(this).next('.toggle-item');

    if (item.is(":visible")) {
        item.hide();
    } else {
        item.fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Html:

```
<table class="patients-table">
    <tbody class="patients-items">
        <tr class="patients-items-item">
            <td>
                <span class="button collapsed"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                Text
            </td>
            <td >
                Text2
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="toggle-item">
            <td colspan="3" class="patients-studies-empty">
                Text3
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Look at the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rKT5n/1/).

During investigation I have found that such behavior is present only in tables. If I do the same with `divs` code will work correct in all browsers.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: I actually don't see any blinking in your jsfiddle

Comment: Confirmed blinking on FF 13, but nothing on IE9 or the newest Chrome.

Comment: I added a callback function that alerts("1"); and it doesn't blink anymore. Instead it alerts...http://jsfiddle.net/rKT5n/6/

Comment: GOT IT: http://jsfiddle.net/rKT5n/10/

Comment: Thanks!!! It really works. But it looks like 'dirty' hack :). I am curious why it didn't work just with fadeId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery you can use the **toggle()** function to get the behavior that you want.

See example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/83tNC/

```
$('.patients-items-item').on('click', function() {

    $(this).next('.toggle-item').toggle('fade');

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try

```
item.stop().fadeIn();
```

Also if you are toggling, why don't you use:

```
item.stop().fadeToggle("slow", "linear");
```

Comment: Of course I tried this things, but they work the same and don't fix the issue.